# Terraform and AWS ECS: Configs/Secrets similar to Kubernetes or Docker swarm

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

Is there anything similar to Kubernetes / Docker Swarm secrets in the AWS ECS ecosystem? I know of the options to use SSM parameter store or S3 buckets, but both are not comparable in their usability the solutions in Kubernetes or Swarm.

The SSM parameter store limited to 4/8 KB per secret, makes it impossible to use for bigger config files. Kubernetes allows up to 1 MB per secret.

And both SSM PS as well as S3 require me to maintain distinct images for everything that doesn't support configuration via environment variables (the only way I know of to get config data into an container in ECS).

**Am I missing an obvious simpler solution?**

Currently the workflow looks like this for me:

1. Create SSM parameter with base64 encoding
2. Create image (for example nginx) that parses environment variables into target files, for example `nginx.conf`, and then calls the default entrypoint and passes on any arguments.
3. Use `secrets` in my Terraform ECS task definition.

Here is an example for a Dockerfile and `run.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "version 1.0"

if [ -z ${NGINX_CONF} ]
then
  echo "no settings received for nginx.conf, connecting with the default settings"
else
  echo ${NGINX_CONF} | base64 -d > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  echo "created /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
fi

/docker-entrypoint.sh $@
```

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY files/run.sh /bin/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/run.sh" ]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Secrets manager supports up to 64kb. Is this enough for you? The idea of putting a full config file into environment variables sounds like a pathological use case to me. It's much more typical to pass in just the bit that needs to change and then use templating techniques to generate config from that. That needs significantly less data to be passed via environment variables or secrets stores.

Comment: Didn't know about secrets manager, I will check it out. But that alone doesn't resolve the need for me to maintain a set of images to provide this templating myself for images that don't support it out of the box. Nginx, Prometheus...

Comment: Can you point me to where the official NGINX image takes an environment variable for the full config file? I haven't seen that behaviour. The normal ways I've seen files mounted into Kubernetes pods is via config maps that are then mounted in a specific location in to a container rather than pulled in via secrets.

Comment: Okay, I explained my situation incorrectly. It bugs me that I have to store files like the `nginx.conf` in the parameter store. And not only that, the only way to get the file into the container at runtime is as an environment variable. And that means that I have to modify the image to take the env variable and put its content to wherever the file belongs

Comment: Yeah I prefer working with Kubernetes or Docker Swarm, but I'm currently stuck with ECS :/

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, maybe it will be interesting for you, here is the solution I have settled with https://stackoverflow.com/a/62792088/7391331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution I am happy with for now:

## Here is how I manage configs/secrets with Terraform / AWS ECS

The basic idea is as following: We store configuration files without sensitive data in the repository next to Terraform. Secrets are stored in AWS parameter store. To get the data into our containers at runtime, we modify the entrypoint. We could of course just create modified images, but that creates a big maintenance overhead in my opinion. Using the entrypoint approach, we can keep using vanilla images.

The disadvantage is that I have to create custom entrypoint scripts. That means that I have to find the Dockerfile of the image I'm interested in and extract the commands used to start the actual process running in the image.

I have a git repository like this:

```
├── files
│   └── promstack
│       ├── grafana
│       │   ├── default-datasources.yml
│       │   ├── grafana.ini
│       │   └── run.sh
│       ├── loki
│       │   └── run.sh
│       ├── nginx
│       │   ├── nginx.conf
│       │   └── run.sh
│       └── prometheus
│           ├── prometheus.yml
│           ├── rules-alerting.yml
│           ├── rules-recording.yml
│           └── run.sh
├── myscript.tf
└── variables.tf
```

The `run.sh` scripts represent the entrypoints. Here is an exemplary `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

require () {
    if [ ! "$1" ]; then 
        echo "ERROR: var not found"
        exit 1 
    fi 
}

expand () {
    var_name="${1}"
    file="${2}"

    eval var="\$$var_name"

    sed -i "s+\${${var_name}}+${var}+g" ${file}
    sed -i "s+\$${var_name}+${var}+g" ${file}
}

require ${GRAFANA_INI}
require ${DEFAULT_DATASOURCES_YML}
require ${DOMAIN}

echo ${GRAFANA_INI} | base64 -d > /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
chmod 666 /etc/grafana/grafana.ini

expand DOMAIN /etc/grafana/grafana.ini

echo ${DEFAULT_DATASOURCES_YML} | base64 -d > /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/default.yml
chmod 666 /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/default.yml

su -s "/bin/sh" -c "/run.sh" grafana
```

Here a part from a Terraform script (ECS Container task definition to be exact):

```
{
  name: "grafana",
  image: "grafana/grafana:7.0.5",
  portMappings: [{
    containerPort : 3000,
    hostPort: 0,
    protocol: "tcp"
  }],
  user: "0",
  entryPoint: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", join(" ", [
    "export DEFAULT_DATASOURCES_YML=${base64encode(file("${path.module}/files/promstack/grafana/default-datasources.yml"))};",
    "export GRAFANA_INI=${base64encode(file("${path.module}/files/promstack/grafana/grafana.ini"))};",
    "echo '${base64encode(file("${path.module}/files/promstack/grafana/run.sh"))}' | base64 -d | sh;"
  ])],
  secrets: [
    {
      name: "DOMAIN",
      valueFrom: "<my ssm parameter>"
    }
  ]
},
```