# What's the best way to store a config file for a Docker container on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, environment-variables, containers, amazon-ecs

I have a node.js app which has a config file with sensitive data. I want to launch it through AWS ECS (cluster) as a docker container.

What would be the best way to store the sensitive config data?

I am currently sending them through the environmental variables in the Task Definition of the Docker container, but there has to be a better way to do that.

What is the best practice for something like this? Shall I use Docker secrets or Amazon secrets manager?

I know it's a pretty general question, but I couldn't find an answer to that, so maybe somebody has a recommendation?

Answer (score 3):

Great question. I agree that the SSM Parameter Store or AWS Secrets Manager are the recommended tools for this job, but they are just not that usable in my opinion if you follow the infrastructure as code principle.

Therefore I keep my configuration files right next to the Terraform scripts in the same Git repository and inject the actual sensitive data (passwords, keys, whatever) during runtime from the SSM Parameter Store into the specific target files.

This has several advantages over using the AWS provided solution:

- No size limit (SSM Parameter Store limits you to 4 KB in the free version).
- Non-sensitive configuration is version controlled with all the advantages that come with that.
- I can easily see the current configs used and update them instead of logging into the AWS console and so on.

---

## Here is how I manage configs/secrets with Terraform / AWS ECS

The basic idea is as following: We store configuration files without sensitive data in the repository next to Terraform. Secrets are stored in AWS parameter store. To get the data into our containers at runtime, we modify the entrypoint. We could of course just create modified images, but that creates a big maintenance overhead in my opinion. Using the entrypoint approach, we can keep using vanilla images.

The disadvantage is that I have to create custom entrypoint scripts. That means that I have to find the Dockerfile of the image I'm interested in and extract the commands used to start the actual process running in the image.

I have a git repository like this:

```
├── files
│   └── promstack
│       ├── grafana
│       │   ├── default-datasources.yml
│       │   ├── grafana.ini
│       │   └── run.sh
│       ├── loki
│       │   └── run.sh
│       ├── nginx
│       │   ├── nginx.conf
│       │   └── run.sh
│       └── prometheus
│           ├── prometheus.yml
│           ├── rules-alerting.yml
│           ├── rules-recording.yml
│           └── run.sh
├── myscript.tf
└── variables.tf
```

The `run.sh` scripts represent the entrypoints. Here is an exemplary `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

require () {
    if [ ! "$1" ]; then 
        echo "ERROR: var not found"
        exit 1 
    fi 
}

expand () {
    var_name="${1}"
    file="${2}"

    eval var="\$$var_name"

    sed -i "s+\${${var_name}}+${var}+g" ${file}
    sed -i "s+\$${var_name}+${var}+g" ${file}
}

require ${GRAFANA_INI}
require ${DEFAULT_DATASOURCES_YML}
require ${DOMAIN}

echo ${GRAFANA_INI} | base64 -d > /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
chmod 666 /etc/grafana/grafana.ini

expand DOMAIN /etc/grafana/grafana.ini

echo ${DEFAULT_DATASOURCES_YML} | base64 -d > /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/default.yml
chmod 666 /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/default.yml

su -s "/bin/sh" -c "/run.sh" grafana
```

Here a part from a Terraform script (ECS Container task definition to be exact):

```
{
  name: "grafana",
  image: "grafana/grafana:7.0.5",
  portMappings: [{
    containerPort : 3000,
    hostPort: 0,
    protocol: "tcp"
  }],
  user: "0",
  entryPoint: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", join(" ", [
    "export DEFAULT_DATASOURCES_YML=${base64encode(file("${path.module}/files/promstack/grafana/default-datasources.yml"))};",
    "export GRAFANA_INI=${base64encode(file("${path.module}/files/promstack/grafana/grafana.ini"))};",
    "echo '${base64encode(file("${path.module}/files/promstack/grafana/run.sh"))}' | base64 -d | sh;"
  ])],
  secrets: [
    {
      name: "DOMAIN",
      valueFrom: "<my ssm parameter>"
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could you please tell me what the Terraform scripts are? Is this a special infrastructure you use to pass on some parameters to your app?

Comment: Or to be more precise @trailnag — how do you inject the sensitive data during runtime? do you use simple shell scripts or Terraform for that?

Comment: It is a bit "hacky" solution, but it has worked without any problems in prod for a long time. I will edit my comment with a few excerpts

Comment: So when you run  `terraform apply` the ecs task definition will be deployed to AWS with files encoded as base64 strings stuffed into the entrypoint, including the run.sh itself. When the container launches the run.sh base64 string is decoded and run in a shell, and that (inception) script will then decode the other base64 strings from environment variables and materialize them as files that grafana expects. Meanwhile, DOMAIN secret from SSM has also been provided to the container env vars and you "expand" into grafani.ini  using `sed`. Did I understand that right? Very neat, but mind blowing!

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best way to store the sensitive config data?

Usually you would use either [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) or [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html). One difference between them is that the `SSM Parameter Store` is free (Standard type), while `AWS Secrets Manager` is not.

Then you would pass "links" to your secrets in store or manager using  **environmental variables** in the Task Definition.

For this, you application would need to use **AWS SDK** to get the secrets in the container. Also [task role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) would need to be setup so that your **containers can access the secrets**.

The task would also need to be able to access the `SSM Parameter` Store or the `AWS Secrets Manager`. Thus if you run them in **private subsets** without internet, [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or [VPC interface endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html) for SSM and Secret Manager (depending on what you use) would need to be setup to allow the access.

Extra details below:

- [Managing Secrets for Amazon ECS Applications Using Parameter Store and IAM Roles for Tasks](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-secrets-for-amazon-ecs-applications-using-parameter-store-and-iam-roles-for-tasks/)

Comment: Thank you, Marcin! Could you maybe tell me where I could read more about the use of NAT gateway and VPC interface endpoints to be able to access those secrets without the internet? I'm not sure I'm following this last part... Thank you!

Comment: @Aerodynamika Hi and no problem. I added links to the answer. This would only apply if your tasks run in private subnets without internet. If your tasks have already internet access, you don't have to worry about that :-)

Comment: — so you mean that you think the best way to go is to use AWS secrets manager or SSM param store and to simply get to them as the "links" when I have the internet and if I don't have the internet then I pass them as environmental params? Thanks!

Comment: @Aerodynamika In both cases you pass them using environment variables. But if there is no internet you will have to do some extra setup. This is needed because your tasks need to connect to the SSM service itself to get the actual value of your secret. I added new link to answer with more details. Hope it will be useful:-)